# How to loop through parent entries?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
ID      NAME         PARENT_ID
-------------------------------
1      Atom          1 (parent to self basically)
2      Molecule      1
3      Cell          2
4      Organ         3
5      Organism      4
6      Child         7 
7      Mother        8
8      Grandmother   8 (again parent to self)
```

Given such a table, how would it be possible to find all the parents (the immediate parent and all parents of parents) of a row and loop through them?

E.g.,

```
for v_parent in (select *
                 from MY_TABLE
                 where id = 3
                 connect by ... ??? ) loop

 -- here we loop through rows with ids 2 and 1

end loop;
```

Comment: This requires recursion. You *could* write a recursive PL/SQL function for this, but you can just as well write a recursive SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

This will get the row and all its ancestors (but will stop when a cycle is detected):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
START WITH id = 3
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR parent_id = id
```

If you want to exclude the row and just get the ancestors then filter to only get the second level of the hierarchy or deeper:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  LEVEL >= 2
START WITH id = 3
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR parent_id = id
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | ID | NAME | PARENT_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | Molecule | 1 |

---

If you want to get the cyclic row, you can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause and check that there is not a cycle in the composite `id` and `parent_id` values before stopping:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (id, name, parent_id, depth) AS (
  SELECT id, name, parent_id, 1
  FROM   my_table
  WHERE  id = 3
UNION ALL
  SELECT m.id, m.name, m.parent_id, r.depth + 1
  FROM   my_table m
         INNER JOIN rsqfc r
         ON (m.id = r.parent_id)
)
CYCLE id, parent_id SET is_cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT id, name, parent_id
FROM   rsqfc
WHERE  depth >= 2
AND    is_cycle = 0;
```

> | ID | NAME | PARENT_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | Molecule | 1 |
> | 1 | Atom | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8108e36537a64c3dcc69fbdcc727cc53)*